# Does anyone know of a closed form solution to the following integral?

Tags: integration, closed-form, error-function

Does anyone know of a closed form solution to the following integral?
$$
  \DeclareMathOperator\erf{erf}
  \newcommand{d}{\;\mathrm{d}}
  \int^{+\infty}_{-\infty} \erf^{\;m}\!(x) \frac{\d^n \erf(x)}{\d x^n}\d x
$$

Where $m$ and $n$ are integers $\geq 0$ and $\geq 1$ respectively. Integration by parts does not seem to help and I have scoured the internet to find something similar without success.

Comment: This doesn't  converge for $m=2$, $n=0$, along with many other values.

Comment: I believe you need $n \ge 1$ to get convergence.

Comment: Thanks, Robert that is correct. Should have made that clear. Have updated question.

Comment: Have you looked at specific cases?   For example, can you obtain a closed-form for $m=1$, $n=2$, or for $m=1$, $n=3$, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Another partial answer:$\DeclareMathOperator\erf{erf}$

$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty \erf(x) \dfrac{d^n}{dx^n} \erf(x)\; dx = \cases{0 & $n$ odd\cr (-1)^{n/2} 2^{(n+1)/2}\Gamma(\frac{n-1}{2})/\pi & $n$ even }$$

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer:

$$\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\! \left( {{\rm erf}\left(x\right)} \right) 
^{m}{\frac {d}{dx}}{{\rm erf}\left(x\right)}{dx}=
\cases{0&$m=  {\it odd}$\cr 2\, \left(m+1 \right) ^{-1}&$m= even$\cr}
$$

$$\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\! \left( {{\rm erf}\left(x\right)} \right) 
^{2\,n}{\frac {d^{2}}{d{x}^{2}}}{{\rm erf}\left(x\right)}{dx}=0
$$

$$\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\! \left( {{\rm erf}\left(x\right)} \right) 
^{2\,n+1}{\frac {d^{3}}{d{x}^{3}}}{{\rm erf}\left(x\right)}{dx}=0
$$

Conjecture:

$$\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\! \left( {{\rm erf}\left(x\right)} \right) 
^{n}{\frac {d^{m}}{d{x}^{m}}}{{\rm erf}\left(x\right)}{dx}
=0$$
when $m$ and $n$ are odd numbers; or when $m$ and $n$ are even numbers.

Comment: I guess the expression you're looking for is “when *m* and *n* have the same parity”.